# Static Route Setup on Windows 10 for Split Tunnel VPN

Tags: vpn, vpn-client, ubiquiti, split-tunnel

I have an L2TP VPN service setup on a Ubiquity USG 3 Router.

I trying to set up a split tunnel service on Window 10 machine so that:

- Internet Traffic is sent outside VPN (for speed)
- Certain Local IP is sent through the VPN tunnel

I've unchecked the "Use default gateway on remote network" and get the expected external IP address when on VPN however, my local IP traffic also gets sent to out to the internet.

I've tried setting some static routes to force the traffic through the VPN tunnel but its not working as expected.

IP config:

```
    Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : routerlogin.net
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ce9:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%20
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.4
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

   PPP adapter AoE_VPN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.14.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I am bit puzzelled whey the Default Gateway is blank for the VPN connection.

Routes I try adding but have no effect:

```
route add 192.168.19.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.14.1
route add 192.168.14.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.14.1

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.4     75
    24.145.xxx.xx  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.4     76
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.4    331
      192.168.1.4  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.4    331
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.4    331
     192.168.14.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.14.1      192.168.1.4     76
     192.168.19.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.14.1      192.168.1.4     76
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.4    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.14.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.4    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.14.1    331
===========================================================================
```

TraceRoute:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.19.10 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     3 ms     3 ms     1 ms  attwifimanager.routerlogin.net [192.168.1.1]
  2    53 ms    27 ms    28 ms  172.26.96.169
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

I not confident I have the correct destination IP for the add route command but I am not sure what IP address I should be using.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "Use Default Gateway on Remote" ticked.

I don't think the Rout table looks correct.
I would think the result should have been something like this.

```
 192.168.14.0    255.255.255.0     On-link      192.168.14.1     76
 192.168.19.0    255.255.255.0     On-link      192.168.14.1     76
```